# automatic multiline label swift

Tags: xcode, swift, label

I have a label and I insert text in it. The label has a size but my problem is this:

when I insert text in label if the text is longer than label'size appears "...." in the label; for example:

if complete string that I want insert in the label is this : `"hello world how are you?"`

in the label I see this `"hello world..."`

I would like that label wraps automatically.

For this reason I did this but it doesn't work:

```
label!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
label!.numberOfLines = 0;
label!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0);
label!.text = "hello world how are you?"
```

Where do I wrong?

Comment: `label!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping` and `label!.numberOfLines = 0` are your answer

Answer (score 14):

```
  label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
  label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

or adjust the font size as below to fit the whole string

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: plz look here for my proble https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723070/label-disappear-when-changing-font-size-to-25-in-swiftm

Answer (score 2):

What I did was use a `UILabel` class.

Create your label:

```
 let multiLabel = LabelClass(text: "hello world how are u?", labelWidth: 250, pos: CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2))
        addChild(multiLabel)
```

You've now referenced your LabelClass file. Here's the code for that:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameSceneLabel : SKNode {


    //props
    var labelWidth:Int {didSet {update()}}
    var labelHeight:Int = 0
    var text:String {didSet {update()}}
    var fontName:String {didSet {update()}}
    var fontSize:CGFloat {didSet {update()}}
    var pos:CGPoint {didSet {update()}}
    var fontColor:UIColor {didSet {update()}}
    var leading:Int {didSet {update()}}
    var alignment:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode {didSet {update()}}
    var dontUpdate = false
    var shouldShowBorder:Bool = false {didSet {update()}}
    //display objects
    var rect:SKShapeNode?
    var labels:[SKLabelNode] = []

    init(text:String, labelWidth:Int, pos:CGPoint, fontName:String="ChalkboardSE-Regular",fontSize:CGFloat=20,fontColor:UIColor=UIColor.white,leading:Int? = nil, alignment:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode = .center, shouldShowBorder:Bool = false)
    {
        self.text = text
        self.labelWidth = labelWidth
        self.pos = pos
        self.fontName = fontName
        self.fontSize = fontSize
        self.fontColor = fontColor
        self.leading = leading ?? Int(fontSize)
        self.shouldShowBorder = shouldShowBorder
        self.alignment = alignment


        super.init()

        self.update()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //if you want to change properties without updating the text field,
    //  set dontUpdate to false and call the update method manually.
    func update() {
        if (dontUpdate) {return}
        if (labels.count>0) {
            for label in labels {
                label.removeFromParent()
            }
            labels = []
        }
        let separators = NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
        let words = (text as NSString).components(separatedBy: separators)
        var finalLine = false
        var wordCount = -1
        var lineCount = 0
        while (!finalLine) {
            lineCount+=1
            var lineLength = CGFloat(0)
            var lineString = ""
            var lineStringBeforeAddingWord = ""

            // creation of the SKLabelNode itself
            let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: fontName)
            // name each label node so you can animate it if u wish
            label.name = "line\(lineCount)"
            label.horizontalAlignmentMode = alignment
            label.fontSize = fontSize
            label.fontColor = fontColor

            while lineLength < CGFloat(labelWidth)
            {
                wordCount+=1
                if wordCount > words.count-1
                {
                    //label.text = "\(lineString) \(words[wordCount])"
                    finalLine = true
                    break
                }
                else
                {
                    lineStringBeforeAddingWord = lineString
                    lineString = "\(lineString) \(words[wordCount])"
                    label.text = lineString
                    lineLength = label.frame.width
                }
            }
            if lineLength > 0 {
                wordCount-=1
                if (!finalLine) {
                    lineString = lineStringBeforeAddingWord
                }
                label.text = lineString
                var linePos = pos
                if (alignment == .left) {
                    linePos.x -= CGFloat(labelWidth / 2)
                } else if (alignment == .right) {
                    linePos.x += CGFloat(labelWidth / 2)
                }
                linePos.y += CGFloat(-leading * lineCount)
                label.position = CGPoint(x:linePos.x , y:linePos.y )
                self.addChild(label)
                labels.append(label)
            }

        }
        labelHeight = lineCount * leading
        showBorder()
    }
    func showBorder() {
        if (!shouldShowBorder) {return}
        if let rect = self.rect {
            self.removeChildren(in: [rect])
        }
        self.rect = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight))
        if let rect = self.rect {
            rect.strokeColor = UIColor.white
            rect.lineWidth = 1
            rect.position = CGPoint(x: pos.x, y: pos.y - (CGFloat(labelHeight) / 2.0))
            self.addChild(rect)
        }

    }
}
```

Here you can set your position, font, font size, colour and everything you need.

Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention whether or not you are using a Stack View. The normal way of doing it (as provided by good4pc) does not work properly if you put a UILabel in a Stack View.

**If you are using a stack view:**

Make a custom label class that will work right. I have pasted one below - simply make a new swift file and place this code in it. Call the swift file "MultilineLabelThatWorks". Then, define the label as a "MultilineLabelThatWorks" instead of "UILabel"

```
import UIKit

class MultilineLabelThatWorks : UILabel {
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.width
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
}
```

Now you can set it to wrap text as discussed by good4pc and it will wrap properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not fixing the height for label.
then you need just these two line :

```
labelTitle?.numberOfLines = 0
labelTitle?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue, I removed height constraint & this worked for me :- Thanks